# How to get rid of repeated lines of statements

Tags: css

I have css file but it is ugly because it has replicated lines of statements. I wonder there is a way to collect all repeated statements in one place and others will use it.

My css

```
#cont-link{
    width:11%; 
    float:right; 
    right:240px;
}

#cont-twi{
    width:11%; 
    float:right; 
    right:180px;
}

#cont-goo{
    width:11%; 
    float:right; 
    right:120px;
}

#cont-fac{
    width:11%; 
    float:right; 
    right:60px;
}

#cont-dat{
    width:11%; 
    float:right; 
    right:0px;  
}
```

As you can see, first two lines of each id has same statements. How can I get rid of repeation?

Comment: By grouping the selectors `#cont-link, #cont-twi, ...`

Comment: Can also do something like `[id^=cont]` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1ed4Lao7/).

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them all into one selector, and just use each specific selector for the `right`.

```
#cont-link, #cont-twi, #cont-goo, #cont-fac, #cont-dat{
   width:11%; 
   float:right;
}
#cont-link {right: 240px;} /* etc */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract common properties into a separate block.

```
#cont-link, #cont-twi, #cont-goo{
    width:11%; 
    float:right; 
}

#cont-link{
    right:240px;
}

#cont-twi{
    right:180px;
}

#cont-goo{
    right:120px;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a CSS extension language, like SASS or LESS.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap common parameters in all elements and then specify different parameters for each `id`.

```
#cont-link, #cont-twi, #cont-goo, #cont-fac, #cont-dat{
    width:11%; 
    float:right; 
}

#cont-link{
    right:240px;
}

#cont-twi{
    right:180px;
}

#cont-goo{
    right:120px;
}

#cont-fac{
    right:60px;
}

#cont-dat{
    right:0px;  
}
```

Or you can use some of a CSS extension language for example [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create like what Scimonster said or you can create one more new class and apply it wherever you are using like below. In this concept you have to apply both class and ID where ever you want.

```
.commonstyle
{
  width:11%; 
  float:right;
}
#cont-link{
  right:240px;
}

#cont-twi{
  right:180px;
}

#cont-goo{
  right:120px;
}

#cont-fac{
  right:60px;
}

#cont-dat{
  right:0px;  
}
```